# How To Return String Value of Drop Down (Select) Menu in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a list of items in a drop-down menu, and have googled for 45 minutes or so. Nothing really is answering my question. I am fairly well versed in CSS and HTML, but new to PHP; so any help would be appreciated. I want the STRING value. Not the numerical value (which is what I am getting now.)

HTML:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
  <select name="list1">
    <option value="0">Select your products...</option>
    <option value="1">Wheat 50lbs</option>
    <option value="2">Barley 50lbs</option>
    <option value="3">Purple Barley 50lbs</option>
  </select>
  ........
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  //Data from user
  $name    = $_POST['name'];
  $email   = $_POST['email'];
  $phone   = $_POST['phone'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $list1   = $_POST['list1'];

  //How to send e-mail
  $to      = "clientsemailaddress@example.com";
  $body    = "Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \nOrder: $list1 \n\n          $message";
  $headers = "From: $name". "\r\n" . "Reply-to: $email" . "\r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

  mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
  echo "Message Sent! <a href='contact.html'>Click here</a>";
?>
```

NOTE: Any spaces that shouldn't be in the code above aren't in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the string, and the numerical value is not important, just set the string as the actual value. 
instead of:

```
<select name="list1">
    <option value="0">Select your products...</option>
    <option value="1">Wheat 50lbs</option>
    <option value="2">Barley 50lbs</option>
    <option value="3">Purple Barley 50lbs</option>
</select>
```

it would be:

```
<select name="list1">
        <option value="">Select your products...</option>
        <option value="Wheat 50lbs">Wheat 50lbs</option>
        <option value="Barley 50lbs">Barley 50lbs</option>
        <option value="Purple Barley 50lbs">Purple Barley 50lbs</option>
</select>
```

also, assuming you wouldn't want them to send the first option, make sure to validate and check that they have actually selected something before submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

The POST will only contain the value.  You can map it out via an array.

```
$values = array(
'1' => 'Wheat 50lbs',
'2' => 'Barley 50lbs'
);

echo $values[$_POST['list1']];
```

You can also use this array to fill the select to begin with:

```
<select name='list1'>
<?php
foreach($values as $value=>$text) {
 echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$text."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to put like this

```
<option value="0">Select your products...</option>
<option value="Wheat 50lbs">Wheat 50lbs</option>
<option value="Barley 50lbs">Barley 50lbs</option>
<option value="Purple Barley 50lbs">Purple Barley 50lbs</option>
```

or in php

```
if($_POST['list1']==1)
{
//then Wheat 50lbs and ...so on

}
```